# Silverlight Application Library Caching and CDNs

Tags: silverlight-4.0, cdn

Does any one have any experience with the use of CDNs to deliver Silverlight Application Library Caching (ALC) data? Specifically Im looking to make extensive use of ALC in my Silverlight application as this will significantly increase return visit performance  (assuming cache hits).

It seems to me much of what Im intending to ALC would be very similiar to  what anyone might be ALCing. i.e.

System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Web.zip
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.zip
System.Windows.Controls.Data.zip
System.Windows.Data.zip
System.Windows.Controls.zip
System.Windows.Controls.Navigation.zip

etc.

Im interested to know if it's possible to do this and what the constraints might be re:sandbox / cross domain restrictions etc, and if so is there any CDN currently offering these files.